# No grub after installing Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I'm trying to install ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10 with secure boot off. The install completed successfully, but the grub menu doesn't show up and it boots straightly to windows.

when I try to change **bootmgr** path to ubuntu with this command:

```
Bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64
```

or

```
Bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64
```

it doesn't solve the problem. Actually there is no **ubuntu** folder in the efi path. The folder below:

> C:\EFI\

only contains two folders: **Boot** and **Microsoft**. Also when using **EasyUEFI**, there is no ubuntu option.

what can I do to be able to have grub for dual boot?

Thanks

Comment: What brand/model system? May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by downloading grubx64.efi and other stuff from the link below:

[linux/fedora/releases](http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/fedora/releases/18/Fedora/x86_64/os/EFI/BOOT/)

and copying them to a created folder in C:\EFI named ubuntu and running the command below in cmd:

```
Bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64
```

Comment: Um, why did you get the file from an EOL version of Fedora?

Comment: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/

Comment: That was the first one I found after searching. But it worked anyways :)