# Can't boot Ubuntu or Windows 10 after running Boot-Repair using USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but when booting my laptop would automatically boot to Windows, so I used the installation USB to load Ubuntu and use the Boot-Repair program. However, doing this left my computer unable to boot either Windows or Ubuntu. It just lists some errors.

Comment: what errors specifically?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try to do is check grub (purple screen where you choose which operating system to load) and try to make it work. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886817/no-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-windows-10) is a solution for a similar problem. you can search the archive more ([example](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=no%20grub%2016.04%20windows%2010)).
If grub doesn't work you can try, either repair windows or remove ubuntu (to install it later again). For this you have some tips [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)